# Integrating SignalR with .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-2

Can I integrate ASP.NET SignalR (not .NET CORE SignalR) with .net framework 4.5 and WCF REST and Windows server 2012 R2.

Can I use any of the versions? SignalR or SignalR-2?

Answer (score 1):

I run that same stack with no problem. Check the supported platforms which are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms).

Comment: It doesn't have windows server 2012 R2. It has windows server 2012. Does R2 version has an impact on running SignalR?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I run 2012 R2 with SignalR with no issues.